# A geometry test question with an isoceles triangle in it

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

$\triangle ABC$ is a triangle.
$$|AE|=|AC|$$
$$AE\perp ED, EH\perp AC$$
$$|EC|=4|EB|$$
$$3|CH|=2|AH|$$
$$|EH|=22\;cm$$
$$|DE|=x\;cm$$
Find $x$.

My solution:

Let $|CH|=2k$. Then $|AH|=3k$, $|AE|=5k$.

By Pythagorean theorem on $\triangle AEH$, $|AE|=\frac{55}2$, $AH=\frac{33}{2}$ and hence $\cos\angle A=\frac 35$.

By law of cosines on $\triangle AEC$, $|EC|=\frac{55}{\sqrt5}$ and hence $|BE|=\frac{55}{4\sqrt5}$.

By half -angle formula $\cos\angle BED=\sin\angle AEC=\cos\frac{\angle A}2=\sqrt{\frac{\cos\angle A +1}{2}}=\frac2{\sqrt 5}.$

Edit: Here I made a mistake. I couldn't solve the question in time.:(

This is a test question sent to me from a student and time allocated for it is 90 seconds. I found my solution too slow. I wonder if somebody can find a faster way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that your solution assumes that $\angle BDE$ is a right angle which is not the case, I think.

Comment: @Vasili Ahhh... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw $CK\perp AE$

Since $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles $CK=EH=22$

Let $CK$ intersect $AB$ at $L$

then $DE\parallel CL$ ($\perp$ same line)

$\triangle ALK \sim \triangle ADE$ (AAA similarity)

$\frac{LK}{DE}=\frac{AK}{AE}= \frac {3}{5}=\frac{LK}{x}$ and $LK=\frac{3x}{5}$

$\triangle BDE \sim \triangle BLC$ (AAA similarity)

$\frac{BE}{BC}=\frac{DE}{LC}=\frac{1}{5}=\frac {x}{\frac{3x}{5}+22}$

$x=5$